# Python gives ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list when removing a tuple from list

Tags: python

Im filtering a tuple like;

```
 newtuple = filter(lambda x: x[2].startswith('902'), csvlist)
```

Then try to remove that from my original csvlist

```
csvlist.remove(newtuple) //<--Gives error
```

but getting;

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

What Im doing wrong here?

Comment: `filter` would return all the matches, not just the first one to match, so "`newtuple`" is a misnomer (it would be a `list` of `tuple`s). Presumably you want `for x in newtuple: csvlist.remove(x)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting my confirmed comment: `filter` returns all matches as a sequence, not just the first match, so "`newtuple`" is a misnomer here, it's really "`newtuples`" plural (a `list` of `tuple`s on Py2, a generator of `tuple`s on Py3).

The most straightforward fix is to change your code to:

```
newtuples = filter(lambda x: x[2].startswith('902'), csvlist)
for newtuple in newtuples:  # in list(newtuples) on Py3 to avoid mutating csvlist while iterating
    csvlist.remove(newtuple)
```

but that has some problems; as noted, you'd need to `list`ify the result of `filter` on Py3, and performance-wise, it's `O(n**2)`; each `remove` call is `O(n)`, and you could conceivably perform one for every element in `csvlist`.

A much more efficient, portable, and Pythonic solution is to use a `list` comprehension to filter the input in a single pass, then replace `csvlist`'s contents with the result of the `list` comprehension. It's only `O(n)` work total, and listcomps can avoid the function call overhead of `filter`+`lambda`. The improved code is:

```
csvlist[:] = [x for x in csvlist if x[2].startswith('902')]
```

That generates the new `list`, removing all undesired elements as it goes, then replaces the contents of `csvlist` in place. If you don't have any other references to `csvlist` that should be updated, you can drop the slice assignment for plain assignment (`csvlist = ...` rather than `csvlist[:] = ...`) for a small performance boost.